# Pass XML string as parameter in Soap webservice in Java

Tags: java, xml

Here is xml String:

`xmlStr="<Survey><abc>123</abc></survey>"`

I want to convert that xml string to following class object:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult.Xmldoc.class);
            org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.ServiceLT service = new org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.ServiceLT();
            org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.ServiceLTSoap port = service.getServiceLTSoap12();
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult.Xmldoc  xmldoc = (org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult.XmlDoc) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputSource);
```

Pass org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult.XmlDoc this class object into following method:

```
String result=port.getSurveyResult(xmldoc);
```

Comment: instead of input source better pass in a `java.io.StringReader` like `Reader reader = new StringReader(xmlStr); jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader)` This avoids encoding problems.

Comment: applying string reader getting this error :

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult cannot be cast to org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult$Xmldoc
        at test.test.main(test.java:137)

Comment: strange, you get back an instance of `GetSurveyResult` , not of `GetSurveyResult.XmlDoc`. Is the code in the question still the current one, especially the `JAXBContext.newInstance(org.tempuri.camswrapper.service_lt.GetSurveyResult.Xmldoc.class);` ?

Comment: ya i want object of `GetSurveyResult.XmlDoc ` which present in `GetSurveyResult` class.

Comment: But i want object of `GetSurveyResult.XmlDoc` this class can i do that?.

Comment: How do the JAXB Annotations on your `GetSurveyResult` class (and its inner class `XmlDoc`) look like? Can you add the code to your question?